# Hosting two web apps with nginx ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have a kubernetes cluster running in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). I've been following a series of workshops and I've set up an NGINX ingress controller. Right now I'm using nip.io in order to access my site. They had me create an ingress resource to expose the front end:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ratings-web-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: frontend.<redacted ip>.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        serviceName: ratings-web
        servicePort: 80
      path: /
```

This works fine. I can brows the nip.io address and everything works right.
I wanted to extend this and create a separate site. I want it at the same address, just served at `/foo`

I tried to create an ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-web-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: frontend.<redacted ip>.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        serviceName: foo-web
        servicePort: 80
      path: /foo
```

When I browse `frontend.<redacted ip>.nip.io/foo` I get a 404 not found from nginx.
I tried added the following annotation based on another SO post:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Now when I browse `/foo` it responds, but all the content is blank. In the web app it's referencing everything at the root level like:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When it sees this path, I think it's going to the original website so I get strict MIME type errors or 404 errors.

What do I need to do to host two websites on the same nginx ingress controller at different paths?

Comment: Can you provide the YAML that you deploy the two web sites in AKS? And do you check if you can access the sites using the port-forward?

Answer (score 0):

Ingress controller will be confused when merging these two ingresses, what the correct order should be because more than one ingress resource is defined for same host.

Referring from [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) you could use a single ingress resource as fanout.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <redacted ip>.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: foo-web
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: bar-web
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Does putting it all in a single resource somehow make it work properly?

Comment: if you have two different ingress resources for same host it will override each other unless you use merge support

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Now when I browse /foo it redirects back to root, and I get the following error in the console: Uncaught (in promise): Error: cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'foo'.